# Efficient retrieval of latest value in a large table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Currently after working to get an efficient way to query a table in the format below I am using this query...

```
select distinct on (symbol, date) date, symbol, value, created_time
from "test_table"
where symbol in ('symbol15', 'symbol19', 'symbol36', 'symbol54', 'symbol13', 'symbol90', 'symbol115', 'symbol145', 'symbol165', 'symbol12')
order by symbol, date, created_time desc
```

With this index...

```
test_table(symbol, date, created_time)
```

Below is a sample of the data to show what columns I am working with. The real table is a 13 million rows.

```
date           symbol      value      created_time
2010-01-09     symbol1     101        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102.5      3847475500
2010-01-10     symbol2     204        3847474847
2010-01-11     symbol1     109        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol1     105        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol2     206        3847474847
```

Currently it looks like 80+% of the query is spent sorting based on the EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Any idea how to improve the speed of this query? I need to get the latest created_time for each date and symbol combination.

Comment: what is the data type of date and created_time?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `where` clause uses only the column `symbol`, the index you created will not be used.

I advise you to create an index on `symbol`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test_table(symbol);
```

Also, this is probably a better way to write your query

```
SELECT date, symbol, MAX(created_time)
FROM "test_table"
WHERE symbol in ('symbol15', 'symbol19', 'symbol36', 'symbol54', 'symbol13', 'symbol90', 'symbol115', 'symbol145', 'symbol165', 'symbol12')
GROUP BY date, symbol
ORDER BY symbol, date
LIMIT 10;
```

Adding a limit will greatly improve the performance if that is an option.

You should run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT...` to get a better understanding of which indexes are used or not and how PostgreSQL is running your query.

Comment: According to the documentation (here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) your first statement is wrong - the index should be used.

Comment: At the same time, I suspect you may be right that doing a `GROUP BY` might be more efficient, but why have you omitted the `value` column?

Comment: Hi Dan, what part of the documentation do your refers to? Ordering is done after selecting data so its not used by indexes. If there is only one column in the `where` clause, it should be the one with an index for that specific query. I have omitted value because I don't know the type (not sure if it's an integer) and since data are grouped its selection will depend on its type

Comment: check the linked page - in describing the various types of index storage available, each one begins similarly, e.g. "A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that involve any subset of the index's columns"...

Comment: Yes but not for orderding. Ordering is the last process done by the database engine and does not use indexes.

Comment: Let me amend my previous comment :/ I don't think Postgresql would use the index because there `where` clause is what matters even though it could be used for ordering. Regardless, for OP, doing an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ` is the way to go

Comment: On second thought here - the OP needs t oget the latest value .. GROUP BY won't work there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137865/discussion-between-gab-and-dan-field).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a partial or filtered index for this purpose - but be aware it may not work if your `IN` clause changes by adding more values or adding values not in your filtered index.  It also may have some detrimental effects on `INSERT` speed to your table, as the index will have to evaluate whether your `INSERT` contains an interesting value - so if you're doing lots of inserts and can't afford any additional penalty there keep that in mind.  You should also specify that you want `date` and `created_time` **descending** in the index.

E.g.

```
CREATE INDEX test_table_ix ON test_table (symbol, date DESC, created_time DESC)
    WHERE (symbol in ('symbol15', 'symbol19', 'symbol36', 'symbol54', 'symbol13', 'symbol90', 'symbol115', 'symbol145', 'symbol165', 'symbol12'));
```

see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-ordering.html

Your query would then be able to use this index and should see some benefit - jus tkeep in mind this index has some cost associated, and consider whether your query is run frequently enough to justify it.  You might see benefit just by applying the order to the index as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without an ability to properly test this over 13 million rows the problem is always going to be the sorting needed to establish "latest". Although I am a little reluctant to propose this here *row_number() over()* is often a good technique to arrive at "latest".

An index that mimics the way you need to perform the sort to establish "latest" is the most likely to assist, so I expect that in index on **symbol, date, created_time desc** would be useful.

```
select date, symbol, value, created_time
from (select date, symbol, value, created_time
         , row_number() over(partition by symbol, date order by created_time DESC) rn
      from test_table
      where symbol in ('symbol15', 'symbol19', 'symbol36', 'symbol54', 'symbol13', 'symbol90', 'symbol115', 'symbol145', 'symbol165', 'symbol12')
     ) d
where rn = 1
order by symbol, date, created_time desc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The index you are using is already the best. Since you do not show the `explain analyze` output I suggest you to try to `values` syntax:

```
select distinct on (symbol, date) date, symbol, value, created_time
from test_table
where symbol in (values ('symbol15'), ('symbol19'), ('symbol36'), ('symbol54'), ('symbol13'), ('symbol90'), ('symbol115'), ('symbol145'), ('symbol165'), ('symbol12'))
order by symbol, date, created_time desc
```